# Multi-tenancy with jdbc extension only

Tags: quarkus

I'm wondering if there's a way to use the jdbc-postgres extension in a multi-tenant way. I'd like to determine credentials and database name when a request comes into my service. Essentially making the Datasource @RequestScoped.

I know this is possible with hibernate but I'm not intending to use that. I'd like to do this at a lower level. Is this possible today?

Comment: It should be possible. You need to intercept the http request and based upon some header you need to decide which db/schema you want to query.

Comment: This would mean not using the quarkus jdbc extensions though correct? I'd like to continue using the extension for the devservices functionality.